# Add `destroy` method to Snap.js mobile panel plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I add a `destroy` method to the [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/tree/v2.0.0-rc1) mobile panel? If it's a matter of simply removing the data / references it set, what would be the best way of going about that?

https://rawgit.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/v2.0.0-rc1/src/snap.js

Basically I need be able to shut it down before reinitializing it on [jQuery Mobile page change](http://api.jquerymobile.com/page/) -- otherwise it will only work on the first page:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/L3dkmkrx/1/

Comment: Are you willing to remove the panel completely and then inject and initialize it dynamically?

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't sound very clean -- although I guess I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: Greetings! Any chance you could show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code clones *Snap Panel*, places it before *current page* and then *initialize* it on `pagecontainershow`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, data) {

    var drawer = $(".snap-drawers").clone(); /* clone */
    $(".snap-drawers").remove();             /* remove */
    $(data.toPage).before(drawer);           /* place it before page */
    var snapper = new Snap({                
        element: $(data.toPage)[0]           /* initialize it */
    });

    $('.open-panel')                         
        .off("click")                       /* remove previous click listener */      
        .on("click", function () {          /* re-bind click */
        snapper.open('left');
    });

    $('.close')                             
        .off("click")                       /* remove previous click listener */  
        .on('click', function () {          /* re-bind click */
        snapper.close();
    });
});
```

> [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/qogemu/1) - [**Code**](http://jsbin.com/qogemu/1/edit)

Comment: Really nice, however why is `snap.js:390` freaking out with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`? http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/L3dkmkrx/2/

Comment: @MarkBoulder it malfunctions on jsfiddle. I'll post a demo on jsbin.

Comment: Thank you my brother, I can't imagine where my app would be without you !!

Comment: nice one. i tested this snap plugging just a few hours ago and after some hours redesigning the panel i found out it was overlaying on all the other pages. I changed the z-index but that screwed the swipe on some pages. I had to make some changes to your code as i only use the snap on the main page. I basically remove the panel HTML and prepend  it to the body when i go back to the main page. thanks for the code cause i was playing around with hide and show but didn't think to remove the HTML instead.

Comment: @Tasos hi :) there was no other way to destroy the panel, the widget has no destroy method. The code is meant to make panel work in multi pages environment.

Comment: I just fired a few snappers at page load eg (var snappera = new snapper, var snapperb = new snapper etc) and it works on all pages) the problem is i see the panel HTML overlay on top of the page between transitions so removing it and adding it does the trick. was that the problem. ??? demo with the overlay issue -- http://jsfiddle.net/L2p4a1da/  -- without --- http://jsfiddle.net/3oq7q21f/

Comment: actually its not an overlay issue its the transition pop that fades out the page before fade in the next. we can just hide and show the panel, no need to remove it -- demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/w2ynofjg/

Comment: @Tasos the code solves using the same panel for all pages. Use `.ui-screen-hidden` better than show and hide ;)

Comment: ahh cool thanks man, i'm still fiddling around with it, ill try that now.